# Split single column data into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Name   time                       type
--------------------------------------------
Abc    2014-01-11 10:41:37.000    In
Abc    2014-01-11 18:12:37.000    Out
def    2014-01-07 18:25:37.000    In
def    2014-01-07 20:00:02.000    Out
```

How to split this data by in out and by name in SQL Server? Result should look like this

```
Name  IN                        Out
---------------------------------------------------------
Abc   2014-01-11 10:41:37.000   2014-01-11 18:12:37.000
def   2014-01-07 18:25:37.000   2014-01-07 20:00:02.000
```

Please help me

Comment: It is a "textbook" PIVOT question. Check it on MSDN. There are plenty examples

Answer (score 5):

How about pair them together (in and out), if that's what you need. Then you can filter "in" and always find nearest corresponding "out" after that one. I guess the answer here can be really complicated or really easy depending on your data (what are assumptions and how dirty they can be).

In the following example [log] table contains your data.

```
select name,
    time as [In],
    (select top 1 time from [log] il where il.name=ol.name and il.time>ol.time order by il.time) as [Out]
from [log] ol
where type='in'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 . . . BUt I would specify that the record in the subquery should have `type = 'out'`.

Comment: thanks sir but how can i get all 6379 rows your qurey give me only 3462 rows kindly help me

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing the data as I suspect you might not have all "ins" and "outs" paired together.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to introduce with pivot in sql server which developer usually use in these situations :
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

for your example i am bulding a table and solving your problem using pivot:

> Create Table #temp (Name varchar(10) , [time] datetime , type char(3)
>   )

puting some sample data

> insert into #temp SELECT  'Abc'   , '2014-01-11 10:41:37.000',    'In'
>   union all SELECT  'Abc' ,    '2014-01-11 18:12:37.000',    'Out' union
>   all SELECT 'def',    '2014-01-07 18:25:37.000',    'In' union all
>   SELECT 'def' ,    '2014-01-07 20:00:02.000',    'Out'

and here is pivot query

> SELECT Name , [IN] ,[OUT] FROM  ( Select NAme , [Time] , [Type] from
>    #temp  ) InnerTBL PIVOT
>
> (  max([Time]) FOR  [Type] in ([IN] , [OUT]) )TBL

Comment: it give me null data sir and only 36 record and i have 6379 record and all record have fill..

Comment: this bio matrix system DATA how to customize                  Name  IN                        Out
---------------------------------------------------------
Abc   2014-01-11 10:41:37.000   2014-01-11 18:12:37.000
def   2014-01-07 18:25:37.000   2014-01-07 20:00:02.000

Comment: can you share some sample data so we can look into it the cause